# Patterns for processing multi source CSVs in Python

Tags: python, csv, data-science, etl, pydantic

I have multiple data sources of financial data that I want to parse into a common data model.

- API retrieval. Single format from single source (currently)
- CSV files – multiple formats from multiple sources
  Once cleaned and validated, the data is stored in a database (this is a Django project, but I don’t think that’s important for this discussion).

I have opted to use Pydantic for the data cleaning and validation, but am open to other options.

Where I’m struggling is with the preprocessing of the data, especially with the CSVs.

Each CSV has a different set of headers and data structure. Some CSVs contain all information over a single row, while others present in multiple rows. As your can tell, there are very specific rules for each data source based on its origin. I have a dict that maps all the header variations to the model fields. I filter this by source.

Currently, I’m loading the CSV into a Pandas data frame using the group by function break the data up into blocks. I can then loop through the groups, modify the data based on it’s origin, and then assign the data to the appropriate columns to pass into a Pydantic BaseModel. After I did this, it seemed a bit pointless to be using Pydantic, as all the work was being done beforehand.

To make things more reusable, I thought of moving all the logic into the Pydantic BaseModel, passing the raw grouped data into a property, and processing into the appropriate data elements. But, this just seems wrong.

As with most problems, I’m sure this has been solved before. **I’m looking for some guidance on appropriate patterns for this style of processing.** All of the examples I’ve found to date are based on a single input format.

Comment: Add a TLDR for us simple folk maybe?

Comment: consider using `pandera` instead of `pydantic` for dataframe validation

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga - Pandara schemas look very interesting